# Is there a way to implement this using C++17 Fold Expressions?

Tags: c++, c++17, expression, fold

Imagine I have this template class.

```
template <typename... TMessageHandler>
class message_handler_set
{
public:

    static bool call_handler(const MessageType& command)
    {
         // Call each TMessageHandler type's 'call_handler' and return the OR of the returns.
    }
};
```

I would like to be able to call the static `call_handler` for each of the `TMessageHandler` types and return the OR of the return values. For three message handler types, the code would be the equivalent of this...

```
template <typename TMessageHandler1, typename TMessageHandler2, typename TMessageHandler3>
class message_handler_set
{
public:

    static bool call_handler(const MessageType& command)
    {
         return TMessageHandler1::call_handler(command) ||
                TMessageHandler2::call_handler(command) ||
                TMessageHandler3::call_handler(command);
    }
};
```

Is it possible to implement this using fold expressions?

Comment: Have you tried `return ( TMessageHandler::call_handler(command) || ... )`? ( Of course you will need to change `message_handler_set` to variadic. )

Answer (score 6):

Syntax whould be:

```
static bool call_handler(const MessageType& command)
{
    return (... || TMessageHandler::call_handler(command));
}
```